# php limit mailto() calls based on IP

Tags: php, html

Say I make a simple html contact form and I POST some data (email from input box) to a php script. In this php script mailto() function is used to send the user an email, using the email addy submitted in the $POST variable.

I want my php script to check whether the person who executed the script has done it recently.

(For example, Tim uses the form, it sends him an email. 5 minutes later he accidentally submits the form again, my script stops the mailto() function from executing because tim already used the form once today(20 minutes whatever))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to log *(into a table in a MySQL or SQLite database, typically)* each time a mail is sent :

- current timestamp
- user who sent the mail *(his IP address, for instance)*

Then, when your form is submitted, you'll have to check into that database's table if there is a recent row for the current user -- and if there is none, send the mail.

Comment: yes i kinda thought there might be a way to avoid doing it this way, no biggy

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the message with `mailto()` the first time, set a cookie to expire in 20 minutes (or whatever).  Check the cookie when submitting again, and if it is there and valid, prevent the send.

**EDIT:** See comment about user deleting their own cookies. This doesn't prevent it.

```
$expire_minutes = 20;

if (!isset($_COOKIE("alreadysent"))
{
  // First time:
  mailto();
  // Set the cookie
  setcookie("alreadysent", TRUE, time() + (60 * $expire_minutes)); // 20min expiry
}
else
{
  echo "sorry you already sent it.";
}
```

Comment: Note that this does NOT prevent the user from deleting their cookie to resend themselves.  If you need that level of security, you'll have to control it yourself with a database.

Comment: ye i was just thinking that myself, if this is the best way to acieve this in php programatically then i think the mysql /timestamp solution would be better but thanks anyway